# C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler when including <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

> Error C1001   An internal error has occurred in the
>   compiler. Logs    c:\local\boost_1_69_0\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp    813

Why do I get this error?
I just include it and I get this error. I use Visual Studio 2017 with the latest update.

Comment: Wow, the compiler broke when parsing the header. You don't see that every day.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, you can log it in the GitHub of this boost project. Any reason you ain't using`std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Doesn't happen for me, same compiler, latest update. Slightly earlier version of boost (1.67)

Comment: @StoryTeller Unfortunately with the MSVC 2017 updates, something is always broken. We are still searching for a stable version where we can add minimal workarounds for the issues.

Comment: @JVApen - So I just live a sheltered existence with GCC and Clang? Makes sense

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for a bug report. An internal error is always something that represents a compiler bug, so you should file a bug ticket.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Do you think a bug report to MS will get the OP anywhere? I think they have more chance in this forum.

Comment: `C1001` has been around for 25+ years, and it's still just a random guess as to why. Try including iostream first. The only real fix is rearranging your code and hoping for the best. You should also make sure you don't have precompiled headers turned on.

Comment: MS take C++ seriously, in spite of their own C# invention. So yes, a bug report is exactly the right thing to get the bug fixed. Also, it provides a central point to publish a workaround, should one exist.

Comment: I tried without iostream and I have the same error.
I have precompiled headers disabled.

Comment: Does not happen to me either (with boost 1.69.0 and VS 15.9.4). Which options are you using for compilation? Maybe you have some fancy stuff (such as `/Za`) enabled?

Comment: I have the same (boost 1.6.9.0 and VS 15.9.4). I don't have /Za enabled. I just created a Windows Console Application and I included boost.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, conformance mode was set to "Yes".

Comment: Works fine for me even with conformance mode was set to "Yes".